# Algebra with set notation and set properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $S$ and $T$ are sets with $S \cap T = \emptyset$

Let $C \subseteq S \cup T$ and let $A = C \cap S$ and $B = C \cap T$. Show that $A \subseteq S$, and $B \subseteq T$.

I said, let $S=\{x |P\}$  and $T = \{x|Q\}$.  Then

$x \in A$ iff $x \in \{y|(P \lor Q) \land P\}$

iff $x \in \{y | (P \land P) \lor (P \land Q)\}$

iff $ x \in \{y | P\}$ Since $S\cap T = \emptyset$

Therefore $A \subseteq S$.  And obviously a similar argument for $B \subseteq T$.  However I know this argument is completely wrong because it was marked wrong on my homework.  What is wrong with it though?

Comment: There is nothing to prove... $C \cap S \subseteq S$ is trivial, and the same for $C \cap T \subseteq T$.

Comment: Intuitively, I understand that.  However, this was assigned as a homework problem and I believe there is a way to prove it somehow.  I just can't figure out how if the way I did above is incorrect and I was told it was by my teacher who is very good.

Comment: Your argument is wrong since the beginning. You said $x \in A$ iff $x \in \{y|(P \lor Q) \land P\}$ but this is not true. The definition is $A=C\cap S$. Where did you use the set $C$?

Comment: $x \in C$ iff $x \in \{y | P \lor Q\}$ is that not correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct, since the second set is not related to $C$.

Comment: How is the second set not related to $C$? If x is in $P$ or $Q$ then x is in $S \cup T$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18929/discussion-between-sam-and-crostul).

Answer (score 0):

If $S=\{x|P\}$ and $T=\{x|Q\}$ then there is no reason to find why $x\in A$ should be equivalent with $x\in\{y|(P\vee Q)\wedge Q\}$. The first statement involves set $C$ and the second does not.